# How would I use php to pass the id to a different script as a GET parameter

Tags: php

I have built a database which can be displayed in the form of an article. The data list was very long so I used some code to only display a certain number of characters. I would now like to create a separate page which show the full article. How would I display on the new page which i have titled: fullarticles.php the same styling I have on my current page titled news.php? I believe i needed to create a form referencing other questions on here. This form works and I can type in the input and display this on the next page. The nest step for me is to work out how to send the id with the full information to the next page. Any ideas?

```
 $query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM articles');
 $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 for ($i=0; $i < count($results); $i++) { 
   echo '<td>';
   echo '<form action="fullarticles.php" method="POST">';
   echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 height-news">';
   echo '<p class="news-title">'.$results[$i]['headline'].'<br>'.'</p>';
   echo '<img class="news-img" src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $results[$i]['logo'] ).'"/>';
   echo '<p class="news-time">'.$results[$i]['date'].'<br>'.'</p>';
   echo ('<p class="news-body">');
   custom_echo ($results[$i]['text'], 300);
 echo '<input type="text" name="article-single" value="'.$row['id'].'">
              <input type="submit" value="Edit" id="edit_btn" class="admin_btn">';
   echo '<br>'.'</p>'.'</div>'.'</form>'.'<td>';
 }
```

Comment: You can pass using URL

Comment: What have you tried? Your code doesn't reflect any attempts at a solution, nor identify the issue(s) with that solution.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use an anchor tag with an `href` attribute?

Comment: I did see something like this on a tutorial, I had no idea how to implicate this though? Is the form necessary?

Comment: `echo '<a href="fullarticle.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Go to Full Article</a>'`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks, this makes sense.. on fullarticle.php how do i dispaly the id? plus how dose php grab the id?

Comment: `echo $_GET['id'];`

Comment: Why don't just edit your original question instead of posting similar ones with the same code but a different description? This is number 3 at least.

Comment: i receive this error: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: i tried this, i get no error,, but i cant see the displayed data?

echo '<a href="http://localhost/deeplake6/fullarticles.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Read More</a>';